# toggle class of .closest()

Tags: jquery

```
    $(".toggle-more-less").click(function() {
        $(this).closest(".article").toggleClass("show-hide");          
    });
```

I am trying to toggle article length for a smartphone size site to save space.

I thought that this would work - but I don't understand .closest() I guess.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/q7kjr/) is a jsfiddle.

Any direction would be GRRRRREAT!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(this) means the items that initiated the function, so in this case '$(".toggle-more-less")'.
Closest will look for the closest parent to $(this) that fits the set criteria, so in this case it will traverses the dom upwards until it reaches a 'figure'.

```
$(this).closest('figure').find("figcaption").toggleClass("show");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6whzQ/

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution would be something like this: `$(this).parent().find("figcaption").toggleClass("show");`

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/q7kjr/3/

```
$(this).prev().toggleClass("show");
$(this).prev("figcaption").toggleClass("show");
$(this).closest('figure').find("figcaption").toggleClass("show");
```

docs:

http://api.jquery.com/prev/

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Why would you copy my answer?