# ToggleShow elements only in this certain div clicked to show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamic content with certain divs hidden on load. On button click the certain elements in this certain div should appear visible.

I've tried the following at the moment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").hide();
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

But the logic behind this would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").hide();
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.hide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jvt7r5qv/1/

How could this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.toggle` elements aren't siblings with the `.hide` elements. As the documentation states, the [`.next()` method](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will select the immediately following sibling element.

If you want to select the next adjacent `.pub-col` element that contains a `.hide` element, then you could use the [`.nextAll()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) (which would select any following sibling that matches the selector), then chain the `.first()` method since `.nextAll()` returns a collection. From there, you can find the `.hide()` descendant element with the `.find()` method and then remove the `.hide` class and show the element.

```js
$(".hide").hide();
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(':has(.hide)')
    .first()
    .find('.hide')
    .removeClass('hide')
    .slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.flexing {
  display: flex;
}
.flex {
  flex: 1;
}
body {
  padding: 80px;
}
.publications p,
.publications h3 {
  color: #393939;
}
.publication {
  border-top: 1px solid #393939;
  padding: 50px 0 100px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.publication:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.pub-col2 {
  position: relative;
}
.ion-ios-close-empty {
  font-size: 4em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 6px;
  top: 0;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="publications">
  <div class="publication flexing">
    <span class="ion-ios-close-empty toggle">X</span>
    <div class="pub-col flex">
      <h3>SDB is prevalent in U.S. Latinos  but rarely associated with a  clinical diagnosis</h3>
      <div class="hide">
        <p>Redline S, Sotres-Alvarez D, Loredo J, Hall M, Patel S, Ramos A,</p>
        <p>et al… (2014). Sleep-disordered breathing in hispanic/latino individuals</p>
        <p>of diverse backgrounds: the hispanic community health study/study
          <br>of latinos. American Journal of Respiratory and Critical Care
          <br>Medicine, 189 (3), 335–344.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pub-col2 flex">
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p>The correlations between the ARES and PSG for simultaneously
          <br>acquired recordings was 0.96 using an apnea/hypopnea index
          <br>with a 4% desaturation (AHI-4%), and 0.93 using a respiratory
          <br>disturbance index based on Chicago criteria (RDI). The diagnostic
          <br>sensitivity of in-lab ARES RDI was 0.95 and the specificity was
          <br>0.94; comparable measures to PSG for the in-home ARES RDI
          <br>values were 0.85 and 0.91.</p>
        <p><a href="http://#">PDF Link</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="publication flexing">
    <span class="ion-ios-close-empty toggle">X</span>
    <div class="pub-col flex">
      <h3>Sleep-disordered breathing in  hispanic/latino individuals of  diverse backgrounds</h3>
      <div class="hide">
        <p>Redline S, Sotres-Alvarez D, Loredo J, Hall M, Patel S, Ramos A,
          <br>et al… (2014). Sleep-disordered breathing in hispanic/latino individuals
          <br>of diverse backgrounds: the hispanic community health study/study
          <br>of latinos. American Journal of Respiratory and Critical Care
          <br>Medicine, 189 (3), 335–344.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pub-col2 flex">
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p>The correlations between the ARES and PSG for simultaneously
          <br>acquired recordings was 0.96 using an apnea/hypopnea index
          <br>with a 4% desaturation (AHI-4%), and 0.93 using a respiratory
          <br>disturbance index based on Chicago criteria (RDI). The diagnostic
          <br>sensitivity of in-lab ARES RDI was 0.95 and the specificity was
          <br>0.94; comparable measures to PSG for the in-home ARES RDI
          <br>values were 0.85 and 0.91.</p>
        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">PDF link</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In doing so, your click function will work when clicking on it multiple times.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/b9zh5u5j/)

```
$(".hide").hide();
$('.toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(':has(.hide)')
         .first()
         .find('.hide')
         .removeClass('hide')
         .slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. Your solution is nice, I ended up using this version, since there was hidden content in the other div too: https://jsfiddle.net/3neg40e2/2/

Comment: @user3615851 - Oh, okay. In that case, just remove the `.first()` method and change `.nextAll()` to `.nextAll(':has(.hide)')`, which would be `$(this).nextAll(':has(.hide)').find('.hide').slideToggle()`. Here is an updated example -> https://jsfiddle.net/5p7o6ark/

Answer (score 1):

`$.next()` finds the next element in the DOM that matches the (optional) selector inside. So `$.next('.hide')` doesn't match anything since the next element after `.toggle` isn't `.hide` - `.hide` is nested inside the next element. So to find `.hide`, target the next element after `.toggle`, then use `$.find()` to target the nested `.hide` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".hide").hide();
    $('.toggle').click(function(){
        $(this).next().find('.hide').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

```css
.flexing {
  display:flex;
}
.flex {
  flex:1;
}
body {
  padding:80px;
}
.publications p, .publications h3 {
 color:#393939;
}
.publication {
 border-top:1px solid #393939;
 padding:50px 0 100px 0;
  position:relative;
}
.publication:last-of-type {
 border-bottom:1px solid #393939;
 margin-bottom:100px;
}
.pub-col2 {
 position:relative;
}
.ion-ios-close-empty {
    font-size: 4em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 6px;
    top: 0;
}
.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="publications">
  <div class="publication flexing">
    <span class="ion-ios-close-empty toggle">X</span>
    <div class="pub-col flex">
      <h3>SDB is prevalent in U.S. Latinos  but rarely associated with a  clinical diagnosis</h3>
      <div class="hide">
        <p>Redline S, Sotres-Alvarez D, Loredo J, Hall M, Patel S, Ramos A,</p>
        <p>et al… (2014). Sleep-disordered breathing in hispanic/latino individuals</p>
        <p>of diverse backgrounds: the hispanic community health study/study
          <br> of latinos. American Journal of Respiratory and Critical Care
          <br> Medicine, 189 (3), 335–344.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pub-col2 flex">
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p>The correlations between the ARES and PSG for simultaneously
          <br> acquired recordings was 0.96 using an apnea/hypopnea index
          <br> with a 4% desaturation (AHI-4%), and 0.93 using a respiratory
          <br> disturbance index based on Chicago criteria (RDI). The diagnostic
          <br> sensitivity of in-lab ARES RDI was 0.95 and the specificity was
          <br> 0.94; comparable measures to PSG for the in-home ARES RDI
          <br> values were 0.85 and 0.91.</p>
        <p><a href="http://#">PDF Link</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="publication flexing">
    <span class="ion-ios-close-empty toggle">X</span>
    <div class="pub-col flex">
      <h3>Sleep-disordered breathing in  hispanic/latino individuals of  diverse backgrounds</h3>
      <div class="hide">
        <p>Redline S, Sotres-Alvarez D, Loredo J, Hall M, Patel S, Ramos A,
          <br> et al… (2014). Sleep-disordered breathing in hispanic/latino individuals
          <br> of diverse backgrounds: the hispanic community health study/study
          <br> of latinos. American Journal of Respiratory and Critical Care
          <br> Medicine, 189 (3), 335–344.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pub-col2 flex">
      <div class="hide">
        <h3>Summary</h3>
        <p>The correlations between the ARES and PSG for simultaneously
          <br> acquired recordings was 0.96 using an apnea/hypopnea index
          <br> with a 4% desaturation (AHI-4%), and 0.93 using a respiratory
          <br> disturbance index based on Chicago criteria (RDI). The diagnostic
          <br> sensitivity of in-lab ARES RDI was 0.95 and the specificity was
          <br> 0.94; comparable measures to PSG for the in-home ARES RDI
          <br> values were 0.85 and 0.91.</p>
        <p><a href="#" target="_blank">PDF link</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sir you are looking for something like this
[toggle class of .closest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925403/toggle-class-of-closest)
this is the answer i like most
http://jsfiddle.net/6whzQ/

```
el.closest('class').toggleClass('class')
```